# laravel config.database.php changing 'strict' mode to true blocks "mysqli_connect" to fail connecting remote database

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am using Laravel for a bit of time and at one point in order to solve "created_at column does not have default value" error, I modified the config/database.php file by setting 'strict'=true.

That solved my problem, but after setting it true I am not able to connect to remote database using "mysqli_connect" for which I was able to connect before this change. I set that 'strict' mode back to false but it still fails to connect the external database using "mysqli_connect" function.

I tried to clear the cashes and look into .env file but nothing helps. I am very stuck with this, any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like there is another issue at play here.

Comment: That is the only thing that I changed and then I set it back but it is messing everything up for some reason. I am 99% sure that 'strict' mode changing is the reason.

Comment: If you reverted the change, it should have gone back to working.

Comment: yes yes, it was stupid Firewall blocking the connection. All the IP addresses of the company has been changed recently and we forgot to give them access, which was the cause of problem

Comment: it happens, has happened to me more than once.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**: It was the Firewall not letting the connection to the database happen. So you can ignore this post.